# Laravel 5.6 Validation on empty fields

Tags: laravel, forms, validation, default-value

Somehow I feel like this should be a common question, but I can't seem to find a definite answer on that one.

The problem is quite simple:
On validating a form, I would like to exclude the empty non-required fields from the resulting array - and this in order to use the default value set at database level.

Since Laravel is using the ConvertEmptyStringsToNull middleware by default (and I am not so keen on changing that), it means that my empty fields will be converted to 'null' and sent to my database (hence not getting their default value, and actually breaking the query since those fields are not nullable at database level).

```
$userData = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'number_of_whatever'  => //if this field is empty, I want it stripped out the $userData array - or automatically default to the database default
        ]);
```

Any help on how to solve this in the cleanest way possible would be much appreciated! I was thinking about making a custom rule that would exclude the field itself (so I could reuse this validation rule across the project without having to manually do it every time we come across the situation).
Another option would be to set it at Model level - but not so keen on doing that, it seems weird to have to do it there when it's already done at DB level.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried removing the 'required' from the validation request for the field you dont want to validate?

Comment: you can try Form request validation. It has `$validated = $request->validated();` it return you validated fields only. For details check https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius, this would cause the field to be set to null when not filled - same as 'sometimes' or 'present' rules

Comment: @rkj, this is the same behavior as what I am using now. Unless I am missing something? The field is being validated, but set to null, so it is present and in the resulting array

Comment: @Ours if you validate the request, then use the posted data, that null would become the default value. My logic here is if validation fails, do not continue. But if the post data has been validated, then use the post data to create the object and rely on the tables default to handle empty results.  Ill try make an example and confirm this!

Comment: There is the [prepareForValidation](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Validation/ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait.html#method_prepareForValidation) method available on FormRequests. Also of interest: `initialize` and `getValidatorInstance` methods.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use nullable rule

```
$userData = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'number_of_whatever'  => 'nullable'
        ]);
```

Comment: please you let me know if this helpful or you are still have problems

Comment: Sadly it doesn't. The field is there, with a null value - I would like the field to be removed. I am starting to think that I will need to either remove the Middleware converting empty strings to null or have a different DB strategy

Answer (score 0):

Hey so i've found your issue and also a sort of work around for this. Based on the below example i've replicated and now understood your issue properly, even if the validator allows null values the create method throws an error and does not set default values.

**Controller**

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => 'max:255',
    'email' => 'max:255',
    'password' => 'max:255',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    dd('Validator has failed');
}

// This throws an error saying that the fields cannot be null!
User::create($data);
```

**Users Table**

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->string('name')->default('Ken');
     $table->string('email')->default('ken@stackoverflow.com');
     $table->string('password')->default(bcrypt('password'));
     $table->rememberToken();
     $table->timestamps();
 });
```

The work around i've devised is this, remove all null values from the post request before it hits the validator like so.

**Example**

```
$data = ['name' => null, 'email' => null, 'password' => null];

foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    if($value == null)
    {
       unset($data[$key]);
    }
}
```

The logic here is by removing the fields from the post request that are null, the USER object does not see them as having a value, therefore allowing the tables default values to table place, but if the value is null this is still deemed as a value so the default value will be ignored.

I hope this makes sense.

**Result of my full code**
[image: Result]

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the time you spent on this - I came up with a very similar solution   //        $input = array_filter($input, function($value) {
//            return $value !== '';
//        });   -- but ideally I would like to make this a validation rule, in order not to have to manually loop on every request. Any input on how I could proceed?

Comment: Haha well it's the first step! I pushed my team to use the new standards of Laravel 5.6, and I don't really want to go 'yeah to avoid the loop we need to remove the middleware' bit..

Comment: I understand, I mean you could maybe make your own middleware or take a look at adding custom validation rules from here, Im not sure though you can take a look here at creating your own validation rule. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules. But i'm not too sure, either way good luck with this one good step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests) and filter out the null values using the `prepareForValidation` method:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class TestRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return
            [
                'username' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
                'number_of_whatever' => 'sometimes|integer',
            ];
    }

    protected function prepareForValidation()
    {
        if($this->number_of_whatever == null) {
            $this->request->remove('number_of_whatever');
        }
    }
}
```

You can apply any validation other than 'required' after the 'sometimes' rule and will be applied only if the value isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```php
$userData = 
    $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'number_of_whatever' => ['nullable', 'exclude_if:number_of_whatever,null'],
        ]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules